# Is there a reason behind this weird noise in GAN generated images?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

When training a GAN to generate images of faces (with the celebrity faces dataset from keggle), I keep on getting ok-ish looking faces, but this very weird noise that looks like fire (and makes the generated faces look unnervingly demonic). An example of the result can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpkoR.png). The same phenomenon has appeared all three times I've tried to train it, so I was wondering if anyone knew of a reason why such a specific- and weird - type of noise would keep appearing? Asking mostly out of curiosity about what's going on- since I'm a total beginner if the way of mitigating the effect is really complicated don't worry about trying to explain how to fix it.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you normalized the images to be between 0 and 1 (or 0 and 255 if they're 8-bit integers) before displaying them?

Comment: Yup- also this doesn't start to happen immediately, the first few epochs the generated images get better and better looking, but then they devolve into being more and more 'on fire' lol